# how can I point PHP glob to a specific directory?

Tags: php

So I got this code to list all jpg images inside a directory but it only works on my root directory and I don't know how to point it to my images directory.

```
<ul>
<?php foreach (glob("N*T.jpg") as $image): ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo str_replace("T", "F", $image); ?>">
            <img src="<?php  echo "$image"; ?>">
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This should work:

```
glob('images/N*T.jpg');
```

Otherwise:

```
chdir('images');
glob('N*T.jpg');
```

Comment: I tried chdir('images'); method but cant get back using chdir(..);

Comment: @FlyingAtom the chdir('images') will work if there is a images folder in your current working directory. you may want to check where that is using getcwd() and after you do your business maybe change it back to the initial value. If it does not work like directly use an absolute path like '/full/path/to/images'

Answer (score 15):

Just prepend the path to the function call.

```
glob('/path/to/directory/N*T.jpg');
```

Note that the resulting array will contain the prepended path as well. If you don't want that do

```
array_map('basename', glob('/path/to/directory/N*T.jpg'));
```

Comment: I believe I have a problem with the pathing... if i don't specify a path is goes to my host root and if I do specify a path it gives me no result images... anyone had that problem with FatCow hosting?

Comment: @Jake if you dont specify a path it will use directory the script is executed in. If you specify an absolute path it will use an absolute path from the server root (not the document root your website is in). that's probably where your issue is.

Comment: you mean the /Home/mywebsite/ one? I already tried it and it still gave me the same issue :/ I opened a support ticket at their website I hope one of their specialists will be able to assist me.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the path to your function call :

```
glob("/my/path/to/directory/N*T.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$files = glob("/path/to/directory/N*T.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

As understand `glob` starts with root directory. For example i see image with this

```
<img src="<?php 
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']. '://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. '/public_images/logo_image_.gif';
?>"></img>
```

Then try

```
echo pathinfo( glob( 'public_images/logo_image_.*' )[0] , PATHINFO_EXTENSION). '  <br/>';
```

and see `gif`. Location of `public_images` is `C:\wamp\www\public_images`

But for example with

```
echo pathinfo( glob( $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']. '://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. 'public_images/logo_image_.*' )[0] , PATHINFO_EXTENSION). '  <br/>';
```

see `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\show_content.php on line ...`

However if from file located at `C:\wamp\www\some_dir` call file located at `C:\wamp\www\public_images`, then need to use `echo pathinfo( glob( '../public_images/logo_image_.*' )[0] , PATHINFO_EXTENSION)`