# Clarifcation - Delete files which are not in a mySQL TABLE

Tags: php, mysql, glob

**[Delete files which are not in a mySQL TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8869322/1575353)**

The link above is to a Stack Overflow question with an answer that is (I believe) pretty close to what I'm looking for. I'm actually just seeking further clarification on the answer given.

---

**The Question**

> I'm trying to delete files (picture files) in a folder only if they're
>   not present in a specific database table.
>
> Just like a check of filenames and if they're present in the table
>   it's ok but if not delete them.
>
> Any ideas how to do that?

**The accepted answer**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT filename FROM no_delete"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {    
    $do_not_delete[] = $row['filename']; }

foreach(glob("*") as $filename) {
    if (!in_array($filename, $do_not_delete)) {
        //delete them
    }
}
```

---

I'm not too savvy with PHP, but I don't believe they are specifying a folder path on the server here, are they? I'd like to be able to look inside a specific folder and check whether any images in that folder are within any database tables. If not, delete that image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling  glob("*") just add a line chdir(""). Then you can search whichever directory you want to look at. I just went one level higher in the call below. You may specify whichever directory you want. Before doing a delete, just add an echo statement to $filename to verify if the correct files are being deleted.

```
chdir("../");
foreach(glob("*") as $filename) {
if (!in_array($filename, $do_not_delete)) {
    //delete them
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5252299/1575353) the first parameter, i.e.  [*pattern*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#refsect1-function.glob-parameters), can contain the path to a directory relative to the current working directory of the script (which can be changed with [chdir()](http://php.net/chdir)) or an absolute path.

Consider this example from [this tutorial page](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-loop-through-folders-with-phps-glob--net-11274):

```
$dir = "/etc/php5/*";

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
foreach(glob($dir) as $file) 
{
    echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($file) . "<br />";
}
```